# How to use asp.net migration within a project?

Tags: database, git, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-migrations

We have an asp.net project with code first and uses Git as a version control. I have made some changes in the model and use the following commands to update my database.

```
PM> Enable-migrations //Already on, so was not needed
PM> Add-migration [name] //Name the migraton
PM> Update-database
```

Everything works fine on my computer but when my colleague pick the last version from git and run the commands he receives the following error

```
Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes
```

Should I upload the migration files to Git?
Should my colleague use the same migration files?
I have several migrations in the ___Migration database table but not my colleague.

How do I use Migration within a project with several people?

Answer (score 0):

You should also checkin the migration files in Git indeed. These will help your colleague to set up the same database as you.

He should not have to enable or add a migration. Just let him run the update-database statement.